# Unity IoC - How to specify which registration to use

Tags: c#, unity-container

I have 2 classes that implement `IMyInterface`, lets call them `ClassA` and `ClassB`. The problem here is that `ClassA` also needs `IMyInterface`, which should be the implementation of `ClassB`. And there's `ClassConsumer` which should use `ClassA` (the one who is `IMyInterface` and depends on `IMyInterface`)

Is there a way to do something like?:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();

//... several others registrations 

container.RegisterType<ITransactionProcessingService, ClassConsumer>();

var specialRegistrationForIMyInterface = _container.RegisterType<IMyInterface, ClassB>();
container.RegisterType<IMyInterface, ClassA>(specialRegistrationForIMyInterface);
```

Code Samples:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    void PushToDatabase();
}

public class ClassA : IMyInterface
{
    IMyInterface _IMyInterface;
    public ClassA(IMyInterface myInterface)
    {
        _IMyInterface = myInterface;
    }

    public void PushToDatabase()
    {
        //do other stuff
        //BusinessCheck();
        //Log();
        //Cache();
        _IMyInterface.PushToDatabase();
    }
}

public class ClassB : IMyInterface
{
    public void PushToDatabase()
    {
        //Actual insert on database
    }
}
```

Edit 2: Code after Progman suggestion:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();

//... several others registrations 

container.RegisterType<IMyInterface, ClassB>("Foo");
container.RegisterType<IMyInterface, ClassA>("Bar", new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IMyInterface>("Foo")));


container.RegisterType<ITransactionProcessingService, ClassConsumer>(new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IMyInterface>("Bar")));
```

and I get an error "No member matching data has been found."

Comment: What do you mean by "should be the implementation of `ClassB`"? How do you know that it is `ClassB` you are looking for? What makes `ClassB` different to `ClassA` to decide that `ClassB` should be injected and not `ClassB` when `IMyInterface` is requested?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resolving wrapper classes in C# with the Unity IoC container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989299/resolving-wrapper-classes-in-c-sharp-with-the-unity-ioc-container)

Comment: @Progman not exctlay like that but close

Comment: @orhtej2 not exactly like that but also close

Comment: @Progman check edit 2... its not working as expected

Comment: @Leonardo Please provide a [mcve], which shows the error message you get and which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `InjectionConstructor` to provide additional information for the constructor. Use it with `ResolveParameter` to specify which specific instance you want to inject. Assume you have the following classes and interface:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    void PushToDatabase();
}

public class ClassA : IMyInterface
{
    public ClassA(IMyInterface myInterface)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Constructor of ClassA was injected with: "+myInterface);
    }

    public void PushToDatabase()
    {
    }
}

public class ClassB : IMyInterface
{
    public void PushToDatabase()
    {
        //Actual insert on database
    }
}

public class ClassC : IMyInterface
{
    public void PushToDatabase()
    {
        //Actual insert on database
    }
}
public class ClassD : IMyInterface
{
    public void PushToDatabase()
    {
        //Actual insert on database
    }
}
```

There are four possible implementations. You can register all of them, but for the class `ClassA` you can specify which instance you want to inject.

```
var container = new UnityContainer();

container.RegisterType<IMyInterface, ClassB>();
container.RegisterType<IMyInterface, ClassC>();
container.RegisterType<IMyInterface, ClassA>(new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter(typeof(ClassB))));
container.RegisterType<IMyInterface, ClassD>();
```

Registering the types like this means "For the class `ClassA` use an instance of `ClassB` for the `IMyInterface` argument." When you execute the following code:

```
var classA = container.Resolve<ClassA>();
Console.WriteLine("Resolved to: "+classA);

var myInterface = container.Resolve<IMyInterface>();
Console.WriteLine("Resolved to: "+myInterface);
```

You will get the following [output](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xla6U9):

```
Constructor of ClassA was injected with: ClassB
Resolved to: ClassA
Resolved to: ClassD
```

As you see, the `ClassA` object was injected with a `ClassB` object. You also see, that when you request `IMyInterface` you get the last registered type, in this case it's `ClassD`.

Comment: I implemented what you suggested above and im still getting "No member matching data has been found."

Comment: @Leonardo Not sure it is is required for you to use names for the registrations, but using names [works as well](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xx5VEq).

Comment: idk why, but its just not working... on the first register type using the `ResolvedParameter<IMyInterface>` or `ResolvedParameter<ClassB>` I get the error as if I had not `RegisterType<IMyInterface,ClassB>` previously

Comment: I had to add the resolver for each of the parameters of the constructor, not only the one I wish to customize